Keras Tensorflow LSTM input/output format
I am trying to create and train a LSTM model using Keras. This is my code after simplification:
pmodel = keras.models.Sequential()
pmodel.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, input_shape=(52, 68)))
pmodel.add(keras.layers.Dense(4))
pmodel.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
Xp = np.random.rand(1, 52, 68)
Yp = np.random.rand(4)
print('shapes ', Xp.shape, Yp.shape)
pmodel.fit(Xp, Yp)

The idea is that I have 52 timesteps of 68 features, and the output must be a 4 values matrix.
The later code gives an error:
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous. Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.'x' sizes: 1
'y' sizes: 4
I tried the shape (52, 68) for Xp like, but still not working.
Any suggestions?
Thank you

use Yp = np.random.rand((1, 4))
